# A problem involving functions with two variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Does anyone know of a problem about  limits of functions $f:\mathbb {R} ^ 2  \to \mathbb {R} $,which does not say the limit name? My idea is to introduce this concept to engineering students for the first time. Present the theory and show how this problem can be solved via developed theory. I even thought about the criterion of non-existence of limits using curves, which might have some physical connection that I do not know.

Thanks

Comment: What does "in $\mathbb R^2$ in $\mathbb R$" mean? This question seems very broad. What concept do you want to introduce and what is the developed theory through which you want to solve the given problem?

Comment: Engineering students have to know calculus.  To teach engineering avoiding calculus is a disservice to them.  As far as differential equations are conserned, enginers will rush in where mathematicians fear to tread.